# installing ssl certificate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I am trying to install ssl certificate in asp.net project using iis express. I created certificate using openssl. How can I add the certificate to the server. I added the certificate to personal in mmc.

chatgpt suggested changing the bindings but the project didn't load in visual studio after the modification. I also tried in iis express to change it but it didn't find the certificate.
what can I do?

Comment: If you don’t know how to manipulate Windows HTTP API via `netsh`, then try to use a tool like Jexus Manager.